# make two bits equal in count

Tags: javascript

I was going through coding challenge when i stumbled upon a question to find out numbers of bits changed or to be specific

> Count number of bits to be flipped to convert A to B

Now, for W3C school, I found out that we can do xor operation

```js
const num1 = 10 
const num2 = 20 
const xorAandB = num1 ^ num2 //this would give 30 
console.log(xorAandB) 
const xorOfAandBToBits = xorAandB.toString(2) 
console.log(xorOfAandBToBits) //11110 (5 numbers)
const num1ToBits = num1.toString(2)
console.log(num1ToBits) //(4 numbers)
```

What I was initially thinking was once I have bits for both of them, I can run a for loop to see the bits Changed

```
const num1ToBitsArray = num1ToBits.split('') 
const xorBitsNumberToArray = xorOfAandBToBits.split('')
let count = 0
for (let i=0; i<num1ToBitsArray.length; i++) {
if (xorBitsNumberToArray[i] !== num1ToBitsArray[i]) count++ 
}
```

So, based on this, i have two questions

1. How can i Make `console.log(xorOfAandBToBits)` equal to `console.log(num1ToBits)`
2. Better alternate to achieve the task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to check wether a certain bit is set in the array (you could also just take the string, no need to split):

```
 if(xorBitsNumberToArray[i] === "1") count++;
```

If the xor returns e.g. "1101", that means that 3 bits were different, so you actually have to count the number of bits set.

---

Or I would do:

```
 const difference = a ^ b;
 let count = 0;

 for(let i = 0; i < 32; i++)
   count += (difference >> i) & 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const num1 = 10 
const num2 = 20
function dec2bin(dec){
  return (dec >>> 0).toString(2);
}
const xor = dec2bin(num1 ^ num2);
count=0;
for(let x in xor){
  if(xor[x]=='1'){
    count++;
  }
}
console.log(count)
```

Answer (score 1):

The binary representation of the `XOR` between the two numbers will have bits equal to `1` where they both have distinct bits. Example:

```js
const num1 = 10;
const num2 = 20;
const xorAandB = num1 ^ num2;
console.log(num1, "->", "0" + num1.toString(2));
console.log(num2, "->", num2.toString(2));
console.log(xorAandB, "->", xorAandB.toString(2));
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

So, to *Count number of bits to be flipped to convert **num1** to **num2*** you will need to count the numbers of bits in `1` for `num1 XOR num2`.

One solution to this can be based on `Brian Kernighan’s Algorithm` ([reference1](https://www.techiedelight.com/brian-kernighans-algorithm-count-set-bits-integer/), [reference2](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-set-bits-in-an-integer/))

> Subtraction of `1` from a number toggles all the bits (from right to left) till the rightmost set bit (including the rightmost set bit). So if we subtract a number by `1` and do bitwise & with itself `(n & (n-1))`, we unset the rightmost set bit. If we do `n & (n-1)` in a `loop` and count the number of times the `loop` executes we get the set bit count. The beauty of this solution is that the number of times it loops is equal to the number of set bits in a given integer.

```
Pseudocode:

1  Initialize count: = 0
2  If integer n is not zero
  (a) Do bitwise & with (n-1) and assign the value back to n -> n := n & (n-1)
  (b) Increment count by 1
  (c) go to step 2
3  Else return count
```

## Implementation:

```js
const bitsToFlip = (num1, num2) =>
{
    let num = num1 ^ num2, count = 0;

    while (num)
    {
        num &= num - 1;
        count++;
    }

    return count;
}

console.log("Bits to flip for (10, 20) =", bitsToFlip(10, 20));
console.log("Bits to flip for (1, 2) =", bitsToFlip(1, 2));
console.log("Bits to flip for (0, 7) =", bitsToFlip(0, 7));
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Even more, you can replace the `while` with a `for` loop like next one, but isn't too readable:

```
for (count = 0; num; count++, num &= num - 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

1: Use [String.padStart(5, '0')](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart)

2: Match the number of 1s in the XOR bit string:

`const bitsChanged = (xorBits.match(/1/g) || []).length;`

`/1/g` is a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) meaning match all 1's in the string, g is global match flag, to return all matches instead of just 1.

The `|| []` ensures 0 is returned if the numbers are the same.

```js
const num1 = 10, num2 = 20;
const xorNum = num1 ^ num2;
const xorBits = xorNum.toString(2);
const bitsChanged = (xorBits.match(/1/g) || []).length;

console.log(bitsChanged + " bits differ");
```

Comment: I so appreciate your answer, what does this mean `(/1/g)` Daryll?